# NullPointer Exception when trying to Initialize ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to populate a ChoiceBox and I keep getting a nullpointer exception.
  I have this

```
ObservableList<Integer> test = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1,2,3);
```

and this

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<Integer> Level;
```

in my controller class and then this in the initialize function

```
Level.setItems(test);
Level.setValue(1);
```

I'm not sure why I am getting nullpointer exception. I have done the exact same thing in another program and it worked just fine.

```
public class EnterStatsController {
    //ObservableList<String> RaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Integer> statBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
    ObservableList<String> ClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Barbarian", "Bard", "Cleric", "Druid", "Fighter", "Monk", "Paladin", "Ranger", "Rogue", "Sorcerer", "Warlock", "Wizard", "Homebrew");
    ObservableList<String> RaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Aasimar", "Bugbear", "Dragonborn", "Dwarf", "Elf", "Firbolg", "Genasi", "Gnome", "Goblin", "Goliath", "Half-Elf", "Half-Orc", "Halfling", "Hobgoblin", "Human", "Kenku", "Kobold", "Lizardfolk", "Orc", "Tabaxi", "Tiefling", "Tortle", "Triton", "Yuan-Ti Pureblood", "Homebrew");
    ObservableList<String> BackgroundBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Acolyte", "Charlatan", "Criminal", "Entertainer", "Folk Hero", "Guild Artisan", "Hermit", "Noble", "Outlander", "Sage", "Sailor", "Soldier", "Urchin", "Homebrew");
    ObservableList<String> AlignmentBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Lawful Evil", "Lawful Good", "Lawful Neutral", "Chaotic Evil", "Chaotic Good", "Chaotic Neutral", "True Neutral");
    ObservableList<String> BarbarianClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Path of the Ancestral Guardian", "Path of the Battlerager", "Path of the Berserker", "Path of the Storm Herald", "Path of the Totem Warrior", "Path of the Totem Warrior", "Path of the Zealot");
    ObservableList<String> BardClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("College of Glamour", "College of Lore", "College of Satire", "College of Swords", "College of Valor", "College of Whispers");
    ObservableList<String> ClericClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Arcana Domain", "City Domain", "Death Domain", "Forge Domain", "Grave Domain", "Knowledge Domain", "Life Domain", "Light Domain", "Nature Domain", "Protection Domain", "Tempest Domain", "Trickery Domain", "War Domain");
    ObservableList<String> DruidClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Circle of Dreams", "Circle of the Land", "Circle of the Moon", "Circle of the Shepherd", "Circle of Spores", "Circle of Twilight");
    ObservableList<String> FighterClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Arcane Archer", "Banneret/Purple Dragon Knight", "Battle Master", "Brute", "Cavalier", "Champion", "Eldritch Knight", "Knight", "Samuria", "Sharpshooter");
    ObservableList<String> MonkClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Way of the Drunker Master", "Way of the Four Elements", "Way of the Kensei", "Way of the Long Death", "Way of the Open Hand", "Way of the Shadow", "Way of the Sun Soul", "Way of the Tranquility");
    ObservableList<String> PaladinClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Oath of the Ancients", "Oath of Conquest", "Oath of the Crown", "Oath of Devotion", "Oath of Redemption", "Oath of Treachery", "Oath of Vengence", "Oathbreaker");
    ObservableList<String> RangerClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Beat Master", "Gloom Stalker", "Horizon Walker", "Hunter", "Moster Slayer", "Primeval Guardain");
    ObservableList<String> RogueClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Arcane Trickster", "Assassin", "Inquisitive", "Mastermind", "Scout", "Swashbuckler", "Theif");
    ObservableList<String> SorcererClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Divine Soul", "Draconic Bloodline", "Pheonix Sorcery", "Sea Sorcery", "Shadow Magic", "Stone Sorcery", "Storm Sorcery", "Wild Magic");
    ObservableList<String> WarlockClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("The Archfey", "The Clelestial", "THe Fiend", "Ghost in the Machine", "The Great Old One", "The Hexblade", "The Raven Queen", "The Seeker", "The Undying");
    ObservableList<String> WizardClassBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Atrificer", "Bladesinging", "Lore Mastery", "School of Abjuration", "School of Conjuration", "School of Divination", "School of Echantment", "School of Evocation", "School of Illusion", "School of Invention", "School of Necromancy", "School of Transmutation", "Technomancy", "Theurgy", "War Magic");
    ObservableList<String> AasimarRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Protector Aasimar", "Scourge Aasimar", "Fallen Aasimar");
    ObservableList<String> DragonbornRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Black", "Blue", "Brass", "Bronze", "Copper", "Gold", "Green", "Red", "Silver", "White");
    ObservableList<String> DwarfRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Duergar Dwarves", "Hill Dwarves", "Mountain Dwarves");
    ObservableList<String> ElfRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("High Elves", "Wood Elves", "Drow(Dark Elves)");
    ObservableList<String> GenasiRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Air Genasi", "Earht Genasi", "Fire Genasi", "Water Genasi");
    ObservableList<String> GnomeRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Forest Gnome", "Rock Gnomes", "Deep Gnomes");
    ObservableList<String> HalfElfRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Wood Half-Elf", "High Half-Elf", "Drow Half-Elf", "Aquatic Half-Elf");
    ObservableList<String> HalflingRaceBox = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Ghostwise Halflinf", "Lightfoot Halfling", "Sout Halfling");
    ObservableList<Integer> test = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1,2,3);


    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button Continue;

    @FXML
    private TextField CharacterName;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> Class;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> SubClass;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> Race;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> SubRace;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> Background;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> Level;

    @FXML
    private TextField AC;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> Alignment;

    @FXML
    private TextField Experience;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> str;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> dex;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> constitution;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> intelligence;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> wis;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Integer> charisma;

    @FXML
    void Continue(ActionEvent event) {

    }



    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert Continue != null : "fx:id=\"Continue\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert CharacterName != null : "fx:id=\"CharacterName\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert Class != null : "fx:id=\"Class\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert SubClass != null : "fx:id=\"SubClass\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert Race != null : "fx:id=\"Race\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert SubRace != null : "fx:id=\"SubRace\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert Background != null : "fx:id=\"Background\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert Level != null : "fx:id=\"Level\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert AC != null : "fx:id=\"AC\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert Alignment != null : "fx:id=\"Alignment\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert Experience != null : "fx:id=\"Experience\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert str != null : "fx:id=\"str\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert dex != null : "fx:id=\"dex\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert constitution != null : "fx:id=\"constitution\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert intelligence != null : "fx:id=\"intelligence\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert wis != null : "fx:id=\"wis\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";
        assert charisma != null : "fx:id=\"charisma\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EnterStats.fxml'.";


        Class.setItems(ClassBox);
        Class.setValue("Bard");

        Race.setItems(RaceBox);
        Background.setItems(BackgroundBox);
        Alignment.setItems(AlignmentBox);
        str.setItems(test);
        dex.setItems(statBox);
        constitution.setItems(statBox);
        intelligence.setItems(statBox);
        wis.setItems(statBox);
        charisma.setItems(statBox);
        Level.setItems(statBox);


        Race.setValue("Aasimar");
        Background.setValue("Acolyte");
        Alignment.setValue("Lawful Good");
        str.setValue(1);
        dex.setValue(1);
        constitution.setValue(1);
        intelligence.setValue(1);
        wis.setValue(1);
        charisma.setValue(1);
        Level.setValue(1);



    }
}
```

This is the entire File. There is a lot more stuff in it and all of the choiceBoxes are throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you also post your FXML file?

Comment: Please post whole stack trace, not just exception name.

Comment: What is statBox? Which line is the one that generates the exception?

Comment: Are you certain that the Level object is not null when the initialize function is called?

Comment: As you annoted `Level` with `@FXML` annotation, you should have an id like `fx:id="Level"`in your FXML file. And the `initialize` method should be either with no-arg and annoted with `@FXML`or your class should implement `javafx.fxml.Initializable` ( [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) ).

Comment: I added the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check If the Identity in the FXML file are the same